# how to keep an object alive between requests in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chatbot

I'm make my own chatbot, where a user writes a message and an algorithm responds. The problem is that I need to keep an object (memory) that starts with the conversation and ends with it. In that memory are stored data entered by the users that I need to use in the conversation and in the end store in database. How can I keep an object with these characteristics? Thank you

Comment: How is your chat app setup? Are you using ActionCable to transmit messages? It shouldn't be difficult to create a message object that gets created every time one is sent

Comment: Post how your code is structured for a better answer

Comment: You can use the Session hash maybe, if you need to store too much information you can configure it to use a database store.

Comment: Rails is a poor choice for these requirements. Requests should be stateless (independent of each other).